Directly access multiselect dropdown component in MUI
I am interested in the multiselect capabilities of the MUI Select component with the multiple=true potion enabled. However, I don't want a dropdown menu. Rather, I want to take the contents and abilities of the dropdown menu and embed it directly in a div. So, instead of clicking a button to open the menu to see the options open in a popover, I want the options to be directly embedded in the page
I know I can set open=true on the MUI Select component to start with the dropdown open, but this has the drawback of the menu still being opened in a popover, and it still renders outside of the div the component is embedded in.
Does the MUI API expose this dropdown menu component directly anywhere?

I wouldn't say this is a good answer, but AFAIK, there's no way to move the menu to be outside popover. Despite that, we might still be able to achieve what you desire with a little bit of tweaks. So, I could only come up with a solution that still uses popover but this renders inside a div component.
The "still renders outside" div is caused by something called Portal. To not use this portal on the select component, we can use disablePortal: true on the menu component inside select component, but since we can't access the menu component directly, we can pass the props with MenuProps instead:
<Select
 MenuProps={{
  disablePortal: true,
 }}
>

The menu should now renders inside its parent. Only doing this, however, causes another problem when you keep it in open state, you will quickly realize that you can't focus on other element than this select menu and that you can't scroll the page at all. To fix this, there are many things to do.
The first thing you need to do is to add disableScrollLock: true prop to the <Select> above.
<Select
 MenuProps={{
  disablePortal: true,
  disableScrollLock: true,
 }}
>

Then you need to wrap the above select component in a box with transform: "translateZ(0)" on the sx props:
<Box
 sx={{
 transform: "translateZ(0)",
>
<Select
...
</Box>

Now the scroll is normal and you can interact with outside elements.
There are actually more problems that I found where you need to set fixed width, height, etc. but I think they're easy enough to understand. Here is the full sample code:
import * as React from "react";
import { Theme, useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import OutlinedInput from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;

const names = [
  "Oliver Hansen",
  "Van Henry",
  "April Tucker",
  "Ralph Hubbard",
  "Omar Alexander",
  "Carlos Abbott",
  "Miriam Wagner",
  "Bradley Wilkerson",
  "Virginia Andrews",
  "Kelly Snyder"
];

function getStyles(name: string, personName: string[], theme: Theme) {
  return {
    fontWeight:
      personName.indexOf(name) === -1
        ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium
  };
}

export default function MultipleSelect() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof personName>) => {
    const {
      target: { value }
    } = event;
    setPersonName(
      // On autofill we get a stringified value.
      typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value
    );
  };

  return (
    <div class="embed-container">
      <div>an element</div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-name-label">Name</InputLabel>
        <Box
          sx={{
            height: 300,
            flexGrow: 1,
            minWidth: 300,
            transform: "translateZ(0)",
            "@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none)": {
              display: "none"
            }
          }}
        >
          <Select
            labelId="demo-multiple-name-label"
            id="demo-multiple-name"
            sx={{
              width: 300
            }}
            multiple
            value={personName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            input={<OutlinedInput label="Name" />}
            MenuProps={{
              anchorEl: this,
              open: true,
              disableScrollLock: true,
              disablePortal: true,
              disableEnforceFocus: true,
              disableAutoFocus: true,
              slotProps: {
                root: {
                  disableScrollLock: true,
                  disablePortal: true,
                  disableEnforceFocus: true,
                  disableAutoFocus: true
                },
                paper: {
                  sx: {
                    top: "56px !important",
                    left: "0 !important",
                    transition: "none !important",
                    minWidth: 300
                  }
                }
              }
            }}
          >
            {names.map((name) => (
              <MenuItem
                key={name}
                value={name}
                style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}
              >
                {name}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </Box>
      </FormControl>
      <div>another element</div>
    </div>
  );
}

Working example demo:

